# Choosing plugins to update with P2 and eclipse 4 programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, updates, p2

I would like to update a P2 repository with Eclipse 4 programmatically and I would like to choose plugins to update.
Classic way to retrieve the provisioning job which updates the repository is:

```
ProvisioningSession session = new ProvisioningSession(agent);
UpdateOperation operation = new UpdateOperation(session);
operation.getProvisioningContext().setArtifactRepositories(new URI[] { uri});
operation.getProvisioningContext().setMetadataRepositories(new URI[] { uri});
IStatus status = operation.resolveModal(sub.newChild(100))
ProvisioningJob provisioningJob = operation.getProvisioningJob(monitor);
IStatus st = provisioningJob.runModal(monitor);
```

The resolveModal method checks plugins to update. If I print the possible updates I will have only the product and not the plugins to update.

```
Update[] updates = operation.getPossibleUpdates();
```

Now, how to choose the plugins I would like to updates? The UpdateOperation object constructor allows me to specify a list of Installable Units, but if I exclude only the plugin I do not want, the system equally updates all the repository (because of product which is included in the list of installable units?).

Thank you.

Comment: Does _[Equinox/p2/Adding Self-Update to an RCP Application](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application)_ help you? Maybe you have also a look at the implementation of the [p2 director](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html).

Comment: Not too much !! 
I was even thinking about the fact that it should be possible to force the update of a single plugin by changing its timestamp probably. 
Looking at this solution if nothing comes out from my first question. Any ideas?